# "Lead to" vs "result in"

Tags: verbs

I am bit confused about the differences between *lead to* + gerund and *result in* + gerund.

Example:

> This process might **lead to** increasing the costs.
>
> This process might **result in** increasing the costs.

In essays, should I prefer one of *lead to* and *result in* to the other?  Why?

Comment: Why do you think there's a difference?

Comment: I agree with Peter; these are simply two ways to express a cause-and-effect relationship.  Any differences would be too subtle for most listeners to perceive.

Comment: Are you using *Gerard* and *Garad* to mean *gerund*?

Comment: _This process might lead to an increase in costs_ (or, _might result in an increase in costs_) sounds better, in my opinion. Or simply, _This process might increase costs_. Also, I think you mean _gerund_.

Comment: @Eugene Seidel: or just *...increased costs.* I agree *increasing* here seems clumsy. It would be a [participial adjective](http://mw2.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/participial%20adjective) anyway, not a gerund. Whatever - I think this question is Too Localised

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Result in" gives an impression of almost instant cause/effect where "Lead to" hints that there are a number of steps between the cause and its effect:

1) Getting punched in the face might result in a broken nose.

2) Punching Ted in the face might lead to your expulsion from school.

When writing your essay decide if you want to give the feeling of an almost instant result or a longer process.

Comment: I agree that _lead to_ hints at a few in-between steps, but I'm not convinced _results in_ necessarily implies immediacy.  _"Punching Ted may result in expulsion"_ seems fine to me.  That said, I liked your answer; I'm not refuting you, just adding a comment.

Comment: I feel for Ted :(

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester: I don't know if Ted's been punched yet.  It sounds like his adversaries are deliberating, and weighing the possible consequences.